# Why is the parent->left not persistent

Tags: c++

Bellow is the code for inserting in a binary tree.The issue is that after inserting the head , for the second input the function insert is called recursively with input as parent->left or parent->right ,and then it is set to item .After retuening from the insert function the value of parent->left or parent->right(whichever be the case) remains NULL and no node is assigned to left or right of head.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

typedef struct Tnode{
    string word;
    int count;
    Tnode* left;
    Tnode* right;
}; 

static  Tnode *head=NULL ;

Tnode* getNode(string const& iData)
{
    Tnode* pNewNode = new Tnode();
    pNewNode->word = iData;
    pNewNode->count = 0;
    pNewNode->left = NULL;
    pNewNode->right = NULL;
    return pNewNode;
}

void insert_in_tree(Tnode* parent,Tnode *item)
{
    item->count++;
    if ( head== NULL )
    {
        head=item;
        cout<<"Inserting head "<<head->word<<endl;
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        if (item->count==1) parent=head;
        if( parent == NULL )
        { 
            parent=item;
            cout<<"Inserting "<<parent->word<<"count is "<<parent->count<<endl; 
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            if(item->word < parent->word ) 
            {
                insert_in_tree(parent->left,item);
                cout<<"inserted in left of "<<parent->word<<endl;
            }
            else 
            {
                insert_in_tree(parent->right,item);
                cout<<"inserted in right of "<<parent->word<<endl;
            }
        }
   }
}

void print_elements(Tnode *tree)
{
    if(tree!=NULL)
    {
        print_elements(tree->left);
        cout<<tree->word<<endl;
        print_elements(tree->right);
    }
}

int main()
{
    string x;

    while(cin>>x) 
    {
        Tnode * node=getNode(x);
        insert_in_tree(NULL,node);
    }
    if(!cin.eof()) cout<<"Error"<<endl;
    else print_elements(head);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you have a question? or you just want us to debug your code for you?

Comment: We are assigning parent->left to item in second recursive insert_in_tree(parent->left,item); 
 call for adding second element in tree after head  .Why is it not set as the left element of head ? I mean what is wrong in this code ?

Comment: Also print_elements() only prints head as no other leaves are getting added in the tree :(

Answer (score 2):

When you make the recursive call, you are just passing the pointer value of `parent->left` / `parent->right` to the called method, but not where this value is stored. Consequently, when the method executes `parent = item`, it only modifies its local `parent` argument variable, but not the originating member in the parent node.

To achieve the behavior you are after, you will have to declare `parent` as pointer or reference to `Tnode*`. This will also give you the benefit that the handling of `head` no longer needs a separate check.

Edit: By the way, `parent` is not a good parameter name, as it does not actually contain a reference to a parent node.

Comment: Tnode* parent , In the code we are assigning ity to head for the first time and after that recursively it should allign to left or right of the tree based on the value of word.and this is not happening.

Comment: Yep. The way you approached the problem, you need a pointer to pointer to Tnode (resp. reference to pointer to Tnode) to make it work. An alternative approach would keep the simple 'pointer to Tnode', but then you have to assign to parent->left/parent->right instead of assigning to parent.